# GAMS- Domain Violation for set

Tags: gams-math

I got two types of error in my GAMS code.

1- error **** 171  Domain violation for set

2- error 148, Dimension different - The symbol is referenced with more/less
****         indices as declared

I don't know where I am making a mistake.

Px1 is my equation name, representing the power of x, so represent as "px"

Px(x,t,w) is defined variable

Sets:

d2  'number of extreme points in the feasible region'   /d2*d2/;

coeff  'combination coefficient of the feasible region of CHP unit'  /a*e/;

x ’chp units’ /x1*x1/;

t  ’time periods’ /t1*t24/;

w  ’scenarios’ /w1*w20/;

Px1(x,t,w)..  Px(x,t,w)=e=sum((d2),Px(x,d2)*coeff(x,t,w,d2));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Px1(x,t,w).. Px(x,t,w)=e=sum((d2),Px(x,d2)*coeff(x,t,w,d2));
```

You use `Px` here in two different ways: First, `Px(x,t,w)`, which seems to match your declaration, but then as part of the `sum` as `Px(x,d2)`, which must be wrong and seems to cause both error messages. That should probably be a different symbol?

Comment: Thank you very much "lutz". Yes, you are right. I did made correction and now there is no error.  the new equation without error is:                                                                     Px1(x,t,w)..  Px(x,t,w)=e=sum(d2,Px(x,t,w)*m2('x,t,w,d2'));